# Form data not being sent through with phones. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I make a web app so you can vote for the employee of the month for a supermarket, but they must be able to vote via their phone, I have created a database on mongoDB and host via Github Pages, my problem is that the database of votes does not receive the request when I try to vote via my phone, it works perfectly when I vote via Wifi but not via phone data.

the app is written in html and uses form tag, and javascript for everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Github Pages hosts [static pages from a GitHub repository](https://pages.github.com).

That works well for apps that don't require any backed server; you can even do fairly complicated things in them (like [write a Morse-code teaching app](https://morse.horse)).

However, you're using MongoDB—that's a database. So you have a system that probably looks something like this:

```
[user] -> [webpage hosted on GitHub pages] -> [MongoDB database]
```

That database needs to be *hosted* at a location that is accessible to the GitHub pages page you load in your browser. GitHub pages is *hosting* your web pages in a place that's accessible anywhere in the world (which you know, since you're reading the pages on your phone over data). But if that *database* isn't accessible anywhere in the world, your webpages will fail to reach the database.

What URL are you using to reach your database?

I would guess it looks something like `localhost:####`, or some local IP (like `192.168.12.34:####`). These addresses are accessible on your *local network* (your wi-fi), but not globally. When you connect over data, your webpages try to send data to your MongoDB instance at some IP address that doesn't exist on the cellular network. If that's the case, you need to think about *hosting* your database somewhere that can be accessed anywhere in the world, from any network. You can do that by exposing your MongoDB publicly (through port forwarding, etc), but that's almost certainly the wrong thing.

Instead, you probably want to set up a **managed MongoDB instance**—pay a service a few $ a month to host your database for you; you'll get an IP address or a domain name for your database that you can use. If you were to start writing an app in 2005, you would probably been told to pay for a VPS (Virtual Private Server) which is basically a computer with its own IP address; you could host your MongoDB on that VPS, and even serve your webpages with Apache or NGINX. That would cost about $5/month today. You could also buy a domain name for the VPS.

Apologies if this entirely misunderstands your problem, and also if this is more detail than you were looking for. Setting up a database-backed application isn't as easy as it could be.

Comment: I think i understand what u mean, but cant i set the mongDB database to be accessible for everyone?

Comment: Not easily or in a durable way. Right now I imagine you're running something on your computer? You can use port forwarding on your home router to expose that MongoDB database to the entire Internet, but that means you will (1) always be running the MongoDB on your computer and (2) be exposed to anybody on the Internet access your database—on your home network. I don't know what you're trying to do, but you almost certainly want to do something different. I'd still recommend a free managed MongoDB instance to try, or pay $5/month for a VPS. That way, you don't rely on home Internet.

Comment: it my mistake I forgot to mention that I host my database via heroku, sorry my mistake

Comment: Haha, in that case I am trying to fix a problem you do not have . There are a million things that could be going wrong—and it would probably require you sharing code for someone on SO to fix.  I'd try asking a friend on a different wi-fi network to see what happens to them. But I personally do not have the skillset to help you with that issue. Sorry! (PS: I hope the password for your Heroku instance isn't in your JavaScript, viewable in the page source?).

Comment: no its not, but thanks alot for you taking your time to fix my problems :-)